# Bargain Finder - cvc-enumeration-valid error

Tags: api, sabre

I'm getting an error when trying to send a request to Bargain Finder API. It seems its related with the "Code" variable inside the "SegmentType" struct, I would like to know what is causing this error and how to fix it and also what at the minimum/required values to have a successful response.("https://api.sabre.com/v4.3.0/shop/altairports/flights?mode=live"). I would really appreciate the help

**JSON Request:**

```
{
  "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
    "TravelPreferences": {
      "VendorPref": [
        {
          "Code": "YY",
          "PreferLevel": "Unacceptable"
        }
      ]
    },
    "TPA_Extensions": {
      "IntelliSellTransaction": {
        "RequestType": {
          "Name": "200ITINS"
        }
      }
    },
    "POS": {
      "Source": [
        {
          "PseudoCityCode": "XXXX",
          "RequestorID": {
            "Type": "0.AAA.X",
            "ID": "REQ.ID",
            "CompanyName": {
              "Code": "TN"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "OriginDestinationInformation": [
      {
        "RPH": "1",
        "DepartureDateTime": "2020-10-16T11:27:00",
        "OriginLocation": {
          "LocationCode": "ATL"
        },
        "DestinationLocation": {
          "LocationCode": "BOS"
        },
        "TPA_Extensions": {
          "SegmentType": {
            "Code": "o"
          },
          "Flight": [
            {
              "Number": 1200,
              "DepartureDateTime": "2020-12-16T11:27:00",
              "ArrivalDateTime": "2020-12-16T13:58:00",
              "Type": "A",
              "ClassOfService": "Y",
              "BookingDateTime": "2020-11-01T10:03:00",
              "OriginLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "ATL"
              },
              "DestinationLocation": {
                "LocationCode": "BOS"
              },
              "Airline": {
                "Operating": "K0",
                "Marketing": "K0"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "TravelerInfoSummary": {
      "SeatsRequested": [
        1
      ],
      "AirTravelerAvail": [
        {
          "PassengerTypeQuantity": [
            {
              "Code": "ADT",
              "Quantity": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "PriceRequestInformation": {
        "NegotiatedFaresOnly": false,
        "Reprice": false,
        "ProcessThruFaresOnly": false,
        "TPA_Extensions": {
          "Priority": {
            "Price": {
              "Priority": 1
            },
            "DirectFlights": {
              "Priority": 2
            },
            "Time": {
              "Priority": 3
            },
            "Vendor": {
              "Priority": 4
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
"status": "Unknown",
"reportingSystem": "RAF",
"timeStamp": "2020-09-23T17:50:41+00:00",
"type": "Application",
"errorCode": "ERR.RAF.APPLICATION",
"instance": "raf-darhlc005.sabre.com-8080",
"message": "{\"OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS\":{\"Version\":\"4.3.0\",\"Errors\":{\"Error\":[{\"Type\":\"SERVER\",\"ShortText\":\"80\",\"Code\":\"ase032lpscil7c6\",\"content\":\"TOMCAT\"},{\"Type\":\"ERR\",\"ShortText\":\"Schema Validation Failed\",\"Code\":\"INVALIDREQ\",\"content\":\"cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'o' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[ARUNK, O, X]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.\"},{\"Type\":\"ERR\",\"ShortText\":\"Schema Validation Failed\",\"Code\":\"INVALIDREQ\",\"content\":\"cvc-attribute.3: The value 'o' of attribute 'Code' on element 'ns0:SegmentType' is not valid with respect to its type, 'null'.\"}]}},\"Links\":[{\"rel\":\"self\",\"href\":\"https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v4.3.0/shop/flights?mode=live\"},{\"rel\":\"linkTemplate\",\"href\":\"https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/<version>/shop/flights?mode=<mode>&limit=<limit>&offset=<offset>&enabletagging=<enabletagging>\"}]}"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

@Samuel,

Analyzing your request, I identified that the service ***$.OriginDestinationInformation.TPA_Extensions.SegmentType.code="0"*** is not a mandatory field, that is.

This attribute does not need to be used when searching for availability.